# Android. How to create button with two texts side by side?

Tags: android, button

http://postimg.org/image/hvjzap2m5/

How should I create a button that has two different texts on both ends? Like in the linked image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use various spaces between the two texts and put the width of the button as wrap_content. If spaces in a normal string don't work, use `Html.fromHtml("Text1&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Text2");` as the string.

Edit:

Instead of using a button, use a linear layout with the style of the button, then insert two textviews inside that linear layout with gravity left and the other right.

Comment: Thanks. That could do the trick. 

What if I wan't to align the texts to the left and right?
Something like this   http://postimg.org/image/7iq0bl65h/